# Was heisst eigentlich "klassisch"?

Tags: difference, etymology

Der Begriff „klassisch“ war für mich schon immer verwirrend.

Was heisst "klassisch"?

1. Die Epoche von Haydn, Mozart, Beethoven (*die Klassik*)
2. Die klassische Epoche der antiken Griechen
3. Klassische Musik versus Popmusik
4. Klassischer Jazz
5. Ein klassischer Fall von; ... ein klassisches Beispiel
6. Klassische Mode, Kleidung, Architektur ...

Was ist damit gemeint?

Warum die Vielfalt der Bedeutungen, bzw. was haben sie gemeinsam?

Comment: Das ist eigentlich keine Frage für ein Wörterbuch, sondern für ein Lexikon. Hast du schon mal https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klassik angeschaut?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: ich finde den Wikipedia-Link hilfreich für alle Fachbegriffe mit Klassik, weniger für den Rest. Und ich dachte, hier ist eher Lexikon (also inkl. Bedeutung) statt nur Definition (Wörterbuch) - und mir fällt auf: nie nachgedacht, worin der Unterschied besteht...

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Ein Lexikon sagt was über Dinge in der Welt, ein Wörterbuch sagt was über Wörter in der Sprache.

Comment: @ jonathanö.scholbach: Bei allem Respekt - aber ich fürchte es handelt sich hier um ein Missverständnis: Ich hätte  nicht gewusst, dass es hier bloss darum geht, ein Wörterbuch zusammen zustelle, sondern bin der Meinung, dass hier auch Fragen Platz haben, bei denen es darum geht, Begriffe zu klären, die im alltäglichen Gebrauch unklar und diffus sind. 2. Natürlich habe ich schon 100 mal in einem Lexikon nachgeschaut, was bestimmte Begriffe wie z.B. bedeuten. Ich weiss auch die Antwort auf die Frage.

Comment: 3. Es sollen doch auf SE Fragen gestellt werden können, die für einen Laien, Neuling oder Sprach-Unkundigen ein Problem darstellen könnten. Das ist mein Verständnis von SE. 3. Daher sollten doch auch das Stellen von Fragen möglich sein, deren Antwort man selber kennt, aber aus Erfahrung weiss, dass viele Mitmenschen hier irren oder "schwimmen"  und daher sollte auch das Beantworten von eigenen Fragen eine Selbstverständlichkeit  sein.

Answer (score 1):

Während es für Fachbegriffe (hier gelistet: Geschichte und Musik - 1., 2., 3., 4.) Definitionen gibt (also Auftreten-Zeitraum, Form, Farbe, Klang), ist das für das Adjektiv (hier 5., 6.) schwieriger. (<sub>Die Erklärung der Fachbegriffe lasse ich hier weg und konzentriere mich auf den Teil ohne harte Abgrenzung.</sub>)

[DWDS zu klassisch (Nummern von dort, Adjektiv ohne Fachdefinition)](https://www.dwds.de/wb/klassisch):

- 3.: vollendet, mustergültig, vorbildlich

  - Bedeutung mit positiver Wertung, eher kein Fall von "bewährte Ausführung".
  - `eine klasse Leistung` = eine hervorragende Leistung
- 4.: herkömmlich

  - bekannte Dinge verwendet, nichts neues, nahezu konservativ
  - als Abgrenzung alt<->neu, alles altbewährte
  - `ein klassisches Beispiel` = dieses Beispiel zeigt alles relevante und wird quasi immer verwendet, um den Sachverhalt zu erklären (heißt nicht unbedingt, dass es vom Unkundigen auch verstanden wird)
  - "hat man schon immer so gemacht und da war es gut"
- 5.: typisch

  - etwas, dass in einem bestimmten Kontext der Normalfall ist
  - eher negative Bewertung
  - `ein klassischer Anfängerfehler` = diesen Fehler machen fast alle, die Anfänger sind

D.h., ich kann mit `klassisch` Ereignisse/Dinge bezeichnen, ohne dass sie irgendeiner formalen Definition analog zu Fachbegriffen unterliegen. Sie sind sehr kontextbezogen und können sowohl negativ als auch positiv gemeint sein, das ergibt sich nur aus dem Kontext.

Der beim DWDS angegebene Thesaurus und Etymologie geben m.E. einen Hinweis auf die Bandbreite an Bedeutungen:

- Bezug auf das alte Rom & Griechenland = allgemein bekannte Dinge
- "der ersten Bürgerklasse angehören" = die "Elite der Gesellschaft" darstellen und angesehen sein.
- die Schulen des Bürgertums/ die höheren Schulen unterrichten mit "klassischer Bildung": herausragende Leistungen/Geschehnisse der Vergangenheit (alltägliches wird selten überliefert oder gar gelehrt)

D.h., zwischen Nacheifern der angesehen Leute (=positiv) und Verspotten der angesehen Leute (=negativ) ist viel Spielraum. Ein Anfänger weiß erst im Nachgang, was ein klassischer Anfängerfehler ist - die Art darüber zu reden, bringt die Wertung positiv/negativ.

Analog zu Witzen kann die Bedeutung/Tragweite eines "klassischen Fehlers" nur der verstehen, der die Hintergründe und den Kontext zur Schilderung kennt.

Comment: Ein Anfängerfehler ist ein Fehler, den viele (nicht quasi alle) Anfänger machen, aber die meisten Fortgeschrittenen kaum noch. Und positiv/negativ ist eine Wertung, keine Konnotation. Aber vielleicht bist Du anderer Meinung, daher habe ich es nicht korrigiert.

Comment: @userunknown: danke fürs Feedback. Ich habe gemeint, dass die Aussage "ein klassisches Beispiel von 'schlecht gemacht'" dem Wort `klassisch` kontextabhängig eine negative Konnotation mitgibt, während das Wort an sich das nicht hat. Also dass durch die sehr Häufige Verwendung der negativen Wertung in diesem Beispielsatz das Wort eine negative Assoziation mitschwingt, egal wie das "klassische Beispiel" dann noch mit positiven Wertungen erwähnt wird.

Comment: Nicht nachvollziehbar für mich. Egal wie oft jemand "ein klassisches Beispiel eines gelungenen Witzes" sagt, wenn er oft "ein klassisches Beispiel von schlecht gemacht" hört überwiegen die negativen die positiven Assoziationen? Wie kommst Du darauf? Gilt das für jedes andere Wort in jedem anderen Kontext genauso?

Comment: @userunknown: hm, ich denke, ich habe es hier überstrapaziert, da zu viele Worte beteiligt sein müssen. Bei Konnotation denke ich schnell an "Kritik" und "Sexismus" - beschreibe ich "meine Kritik ist" oder "das ist Sexismus", dann hört der Gegner "sofort&nur" den negativen Teil, obwohl es positive&negative Kritik gibt und angewandter Sexismus nicht pauschal negativ ist.

Comment: @userunknown Solange "klassisch" nicht primär wertend gebraucht wird, sondern beschreibend (z.B. als "typisch") muss jede wertende Komponente wohl eine _Neben_bedeutung, eine Konnotation sein. (Wobei hier in vielen Beispielen natürlich die Wertung gar nicht im Wort "klassisch" steckt, sondern in der Bedeutung des ganzen Satzes.) Ich kenne nur wenige Beispiele, wo "klassisch" wirklich eine negative Konnotation haben kann, etwa in einem akademischen Feld, das sich der Dekonstruktion von bisherigen Annahmen verschrieben hat - da wird dann "klassisch" geradezu zur Beleidigung.

Comment: @sgf: Wenn Du von einem klassischen Rennrad sprichst, dann stelle ich mir ein dünnes Stahlrahmenrennrad vor, Schalthebel am Rohr, keine Scheibenbremsen, ... Du kannst moderne Rennräder vorziehen oder verachten und beide Male von klassischen Rennrädern als Gegensatz sprechen, das verrät Deine Bewertung meines Erachtens nicht. Mimik, Gestik, Tonfall und weitere Informationen, insbesondere explizite Bekenntnisse erst verraten die Wertung, wenn eine auftauchen sollte.

Comment: @userunknown Ja, ich glaube hier sind wir uns einig. Mein Punkt ist ja nur, dass zwischen "Bedeutung mit positiver Konnotation" und "Bedeutung mit positiver Wertung" nicht wirklich ein Unterschied besteht: Solange es Teil der Bedeutung, aber nicht die eigentliche Bedeutung ist, muss es wohl die Konnotation sein. Wenn es keine Konnotation ist, dann ist die Bewertung kontextabhängig.

Comment: @user-unknown einer Theorie nach (s. [hier](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/32031/22504)), die nur begrenzt akzeptiert wird (den entsprechenden Kommentar müsste ich erst widerfinden, könnte mich auch irren; finde es jedenfalls fragwürdig, bzw. ausbaufähig), werden verschiedene Ebenen der Konnotation unterschieden. Dabei erschließt sich mir "evaluative" nicht ganz, aber genau das könnte hier gemeint gewesen sein. Hat das noch was mit der Frage zu tun? Zeigt *klassisch* mehr als fünf Ebenen der Ableitung (ohne *rebase* oder *fork* im Jargon von Versionskontrolle)? ...

Comment: *el classico*, das Fußballmatch zwischen Madrid und Barcelon (w.i.m.r.e.; hauptsache Italien wie Mattheus sagte) z.B. deutet eher auf *clash [of the titans]*, und *clash* ist z.B. stark negative connotiert, im entsprechenden Kontext jedenfalls (bspw. *clashing colors*, was zwischenzeitlich auch mal modern sein kann), wenngleich das mit Deutsch nicht viel zu tun hat, geschweigen den Anfängerfehlern. Die könnte man im gegebenen Kontext aber scherzhaft eben auch einfach mit "Ha, ein Klassiker" auskommentieren.

Comment: Hinsichtlich *clash* (lt. e.wt onomatopoetisch, verwandt zu *klatschen*) vergleich *einschlagen wie eine Bombe*, *einen gewissen Einschlag haben *, *einschlägig bekannt*, und *den Schlager* (Borussia vs. München), sowie *Kassenschlager* (cp "blockbuster"?) *Schlagersänger*, *Gassenhauer*, *ein Schlag aus dem Leben erzählen* (?), und cetera

Comment: @Vectory: Ich weiß nicht welche Frage Du zu stellen oder zu klären versuchst. Meine Aussage ist schlicht, dass ein "klassischer Anfängerfehler" deswegen als negativ betrachtet wird, weil wir Fehler als negativ betrachten, mit "klassisch" hat es nichts zu tun, und die Kaffeesatzleserei mit Konnotationen ist meist Sprachesoterik für Lobotomierte. Mit Hilfe von Kontexten wird den Wörtern eine Bedeutung angedichtet, die meist nur aus dem Kontext kommt, nicht aus dem Wort. Die Zwanghaftigkeit, mit der man Begriffe in das duale Schema von pos. u. neg. einordnen will, operiert auf Kindergartenniveau.

Answer (score -1):

Eine weitere Bedeutung, die in der Frage nicht aufgelistet ist, ist *klassische Physik*.

> Die klassische Physik umfasst die Teilgebiete der Physik, die ohne die Konzepte der Quantisierung und der vierdimensionalen Raumzeit auskommen.

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klassische_Physik

Comment: Find ich interessant zur Einsortierung (entspricht mMn. "althergebracht"), fällt für mich unter "Fachbegriff" - und ich habe jegliche Mühe gescheut, alle klassischen Fachbegriffe einzusammeln :-o

Comment: Mit oben aufgelistet meinte ich tatsächlich nicht deine Antwort sondern den OP.

Comment: Its das nicht eher ein Kommentar zur Frage, denn eine Antwort?

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage primär als, was klassisch alles bedeuten kann und sehe meine Antwort als ergänzend. Man könnte kommentieren, dass es im OP nicht auftaucht, aber dann muss man es ja trotzdem beantworten

Comment: @infinitezero: genau